# Openlayers 3 GPX Shape issue

Tags: openlayers, xml, gpx

I've been working to incorporate GPX file handling within my application with a pretty good degree of success but have just encountered an issue which I don't know how to solve.

When drag/dropping a file which contains shapes I've discovered that these are incorrectly interpreted as routes and it seems that the API can not read the extensions node by default. The trouble is I have no idea how to configure the readExtensions function of the GPX format to deal with this.

I don't really want to have to parse these features manually as the default drag/drop parsing is superfast and I'm sure there'd be a performance hit. This is what I have so far...

```
 var CustomFormatGPX = function () {
    ol.format.GPX.call(this, {
        // custom options
        readExtensions: function (feature, extensionsNode) {
            console.log(extensionsNode);
            console.log(feature);
        }
    });
};
ol.inherits(CustomFormatGPX, ol.format.GPX);

session.routeFeaturesGPX = formatGPX.writeFeatures(event.features);
```

So event.features is Openlayers' GeoJSON interpretation of the information and formatGPX.writeFeatures will rewrite this as GPX albeit without reading the extensions correctly. Is there a third party solution which will reparse this as GeoJSON or am I approaching this the wrong way?

There is an [issue on the OL3 Github pages](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1791) but my javascript knowledge is sometimes deficient and I'm struggling to understand what to place in this function. A colleague suggested XPath to try to read and manipulate the data but apparently cross-browser support is patchy. Does anyone have any experience of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to solve this although I'm not sure how 'hacky' the solution might be.

The problem I encountered IMHO is a common one because the GPX schema doesn't support polygon shapes and therefore renders these as open-ended routes. Many of the other systems I tested worked this way and it was therefore necessary to interrupt the generation of features in order to re-interpret any offenders in the right way.

By extending the native ol3 gpx format I was able to read and redraw the features where necessary. As it's helped me I thought I'd share the code in case anyone else encounters the problem.

```
var CustomFormatGPX = function () {
ol.format.GPX.call(this, {
    // custom options
    readExtensions: function (feature, extensionsNode) {
        if (extensionsNode == null) {
            return;
        }
        console.log(extensionsNode);
        console.log(feature);

        session.gpxFeature = xml2json(extensionsNode, '');
        session.gpxFeature = JSON.parse(session.gpxFeature);

        var typeNodes = jsonPath(session.gpxFeature, '$..Shape.Type').toString();

        if (typeNodes == "Area") {
            console.log(feature);
            console.info(session.gpxFeature);
            var coords = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Polygon([coords]));
        }
    }
});
};

ol.inherits(CustomFormatGPX, ol.format.GPX);
```

It was necessary to utilise two 3rd-party libraries, [xml2json](https://github.com/enkidootech/xml2json/) and [jsonPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) and my thanks go to the respective authors.