# Convert Geometry Type in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, gpx, geometry-conversion

I'm wondering if anyone can help me to understand if there is a way to convert an existing feature's geometry type? The reason for this is outlined in a [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199610/openlayers-3-gpx-shape-issue) but basically when I drop a gpx file onto the map I need to convert certain 'routes' to shapes.

The API indicates that there is a setGeometry() function but I can't get it to work and there are no examples to draw from. Below are the methods I've tried so far.

```
feature.setGeometry(ol.geom.Polygon);
feature.setGeometry('Polygon');
feature.setGeometry(geometry, ol.geom.Polygon);
feature.values_.geometry = ol.geom.Polygon;
feature.getGeometry().setType('Polygon');
```

This might be a kludge but the only other alternative as far as I can tell is to  parse every gpx element manually which will involve essentially replicating all the existing code in order to catch this error.

Comment: setGeometry is used like this:
`feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point([1,2]));`

Comment: @ca0v thanks so much, I didn't realise the new constructor or coordinates were necessary - this now works like a charm! I don't know if you want to post your comment as an answer and I can accept it? Thanks again ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[setGeometry](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#setGeometry) is used like this:

```
feature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point([1,2]));
```

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, this works perfectly now. Thanks again @ca0v